# search value of its corresponding date within the range of date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to find if the data of its corresponding date is in the next working date.

I use =VLOOKUP(WORKDAY(A2,1),A:B,2,FALSE)=B2 but the problem is I have numerous data like almost 10,000 rows in a single date

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "but the problem is I have numerous data"-why is that a problem? Do you get wrong result? Poor performance?

Answer (score 0):

*Since you have not shared sample data therefore I'm assuming that you have data in `A2:B1000` and criteria in Cell `A1`.*

- Enter this array (CSE) formula in cell `C2`, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** and fill across.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$B$1000,SMALL(IF((INDEX($A$2:$B$1000,,2)=WORKDAY($A$1,1)),MATCH(ROW($A$2:$B$1000),ROW($A$2:$B$1000)),""),ROWS(C1:$C$1)),COLUMNS($A$1:A1)),"")}
  ```

**N.B.**

- In `(INDEX($A$2:$B$1000,,2)`, **2** is column number i.e `B` in range `A2:B1000`, has Date to match with cell `A1`, is editable.
- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: The OP stated *'10,000 rows'*, not *'1,000 rows'*

Comment: Dear @Jeeped,,, cell references in the formula is/are always editable ,, and bottom line of my post justifies this too. !!

Comment: Write your concern,, Y this has been down voted??

Comment: +1 The downvote wasn't justified. The question is also being reviewed: [link](https://superuser.com/review/close/941839)

Comment: Thanks @karel,,, yes U are true,, unnecessary down vote discourage us.

Comment: Sorry Rajesh but I wasn't the down-voter TBH, I don't know if this is a correct response or not since I cannot determine what the original question is asking. All I was commenting on was the fact that you seemed to have missed a zero in your formula

Comment: @Jeeped,, difficult to say especially who has down voted,, if person exercises without valid reason, it's quite frustrating,, I always expect that readers including OP come with reason and their concern,, helps me and others to fix the issue in better way.  And about 10000 instead of 1000 ,, we all know is not a crucial issue,, cell references is/are editable,, and I always mention with my every post also.

Answer (score -1):

1. Various dates for the data is in the column A
2. Data for the given date is in column B, C, D,…etc.
3. So data is row wise.
4. Suppose your today's date is stored in cell J1 using formula  `=today()`
5. Now in the last column you enter the formula as given in Step 6.
6. `=if(A2-$j$1)=1),"Next Day", "")`
7. Copy the formula of step 6 down the rows.
8. So every day the current date would be used as per system date in Cell J1.
9. You can sort, or give colour using conditional formatting to highlight the next day jobs.

Comment: Friday's *next workday* is typically Monday, not Saturday.